# PS3 Controller - Wrong Number

Tags: ps3

I'm running 16.04 and I'm trying to get my PS3 controllers working. I've got them paired, but no matter what I do they connect as players 2 & 4. This causes them to not work properly with Retropie.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

TYIA

Edit: I should mention that this behavior happens before I have anything else installed (with the exception of the Ubuntu updates), so it doesn't seem to be a RetroPie issue.

Comment: I tried doing a clean install of Ubuntu, and it was working fine until the software manager told me there was an update for Ubuntu. Now it's doing the same thing. So something with the update is breaking functionality.

Comment: Also tried installing 17.10 with the same results.